# React Native Show custom message after Capturing image

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I am trying to show a message to the user after he captures an image and the image is saved in gallery. I have surfed through the net but can not find any solution. So far what I have tried the following code from [here](https://github.com/expo/camerja/blob/master/App.js) for capturing image-

```
takePicture = async function() {
if (this.camera) {
  this.camera.takePicture().then(data => {
    FileSystem.moveAsync({
      from: data,
      to: `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}photos/Photo_${this.state
        .photoId}.jpg`,
    }).then(() => {
      this.setState({
        photoId: this.state.photoId + 1,
      });
      Vibration.vibrate();
    });
  });
}
};
```

Now I want to know what should I do to get the completion event. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not the best with what all to put in that code, but you can make a message show this way:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Picture taken!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Toast is not available in react native only ToastAndroid but ToastAndroid is not available in ios. So which plugin would you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Toast you can use a cross platform library : [react-native-dropdown-alert](https://github.com/testshallpass/react-native-dropdownalert)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how can i integrate it with react native camera view. i need an action after the camera picture is taken.

Comment: U can do this library related code inside then() after setState is called

Comment: i'm not very good at react or react-native so it will be very helpful could you please give me an example